# php error log per vhost

Tags: virtualhost, apache2, ubuntu-16.04, php7

I have had no problems with separate php_error logs per vhosts in the past.

I have recently installed a server with Ubuntu 16.04, using php7 on apache2.

my vhost reads:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName examp.com
    Header always unset X-Frame-Options
    DocumentRoot /var/www/sos/rtg/html
    ErrorLog /var/www/sos/rtg/error.log
    CustomLog /var/www/sos/rtg/access.log combined
    php_flag log_errors on
    php_flag display_errors on
    php_value error_reporting 2147483647
    php_value error_log /var/www/sos/rtg/php_error.log
    php_admin_value error_log "/var/www/sos/rtg/php_error.log"
</VirtualHost>
```

Based on internet recommendations, I have touch 'ed php_error.log and adjusted privileges. chown and chmod all different possibilities. I cannot seem to get php to write to an error log other than apache's error.log

I have had this working in all other servers I have (albeit ubuntu 14, apache2 and php5)

Comment: But what is your question? What problem do you have? Do not touch any file, let Apache create them as needed. Make sure that all `/var`, `/var/www`, `/var/www/sos` are readable+executable for the user under which Apache runs, and that `/var/www/sos/rtg/` is readable+executable+writable for the same user, in order for it to be able to create files in it.

Comment: I did the touch on the advise of another website.  I normalized that trial.  Apache creates error.log and access.log in the directory fine. I do know that the php_flag display_errors on is working, because if I comment that, it doe not display on screen errors...

Answer (score 2):

```
touch /path/to/php_error.log
chown www-data:www-data php_error.log
chmod 755 php_error.log
```

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35731760/php-cant-write-to-error-log-permission-denied

led me to the answer